# How to load View with PartialView already loaded in it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am working on this `ASP.NET MVC Core` project where I want to a `View` to be rendered on the screen with the `PartialView` already rendered in the `View`. In other words,

I have the following `View`:

**View: Index.cshtml**

```
...
...
<div class="card">
    <div id="divPageLoad"></div>
</div>
```

**PartialView: Details.cshtml**

```
...
...
// Some code
...
...
```

I want to render `Details.cshtml` in `divPageLoad` of `Index.cshtml` when `Index.cshtml` loads on the screen. In other words, it should seem as if the contents of `Index.cshtml` and `Details.cshtml` exist on one page, where in reality, they are two different `Views`.

I am presently making it work in the following way:

```
<div class="card">
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" id="lnk_InventoryDetails" onClick="GetInventoryDetails()">Details</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="/Inventory/Locate">Locate</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="pageLoadId"></div>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetInventoryDetails() {
        $('#divPageLoad').load("/Constructor/Action");

    };
</script>
```

I have used `onClick()`. But I know that in this way, the page will load only after that`Button` is clicked. Else it won't run. I basically want to replace `onClick()` with something else, or take a different approach.

Comment: Why not use @Html.Partial("PartialViewName") or @Html.Partial("PartialViewName", Model) in your main View

Comment: if it's an action to get the partial view you can also use `@Html.Action("Controller","Action")`

Comment: @RyanWilson, could you post an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer as requested:

```
<div class="card">
    <div id="divPageLoad"></div>
</div>

@Html.Partial("PartialViewName")
```

OR

```
@Html.Partial("PartialViewName", Model) //If you need to pass a model object to partial
```